# C# Creating file - UnauthorizedAccessException with FileMode.Create

Tags: c#, file, io

I am trying to create a text file and write to it using `FileMode.Create`.
Here is my code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "hello.txt");
using (StreamWriter writer = new(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
{
    writer.WriteLine("123");
}
```

The second line (with `using`) throws an exception: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\linds\Desktop\hello.txt' is denied.'`

`FileMode.CreateNew` works fine (123 is written and a file created)

`FileMode.OpenOrCreate` works fine only if the file doesn't exist yet, otherwise an exception. `FileMode.Open` throws an exception. How is the program capable of creating file an writing to it, but incapable of modifying an existing file? And why `FileMode.Create` can't even do that? Running from administrator doesn't help.

**UPD**

I have tried doing it in D:\ drive and then it works. So it's OS-related.

Comment: Have you tried to manually set the permissions on the [`FileSystemRights`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0)?

Comment: @osfresia I'm not sure If I'm doing it right, but I tried changing directory's rights (with FileMode.Create) and file's rights (with FileMode.Open on existing file) like this: ` `FileInfo finf = new(path); FileSecurity fsec = finf.GetAccessControl(); fsec.AddAccessRule(new("linds", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow)); finf.SetAccessControl(fsec);`

and analogically with DirectorySecurity
but to no avail...